How to deal with missing census years in a panel dataset?
I am working with a panel dataset:

Years is from 2006 to 2015
spatial units are SA2s (suburbs in Australia)

I have data for all years (2006-2015) for my dependent and main predictors, but for most of my controls, the data comes from the census and hence I only have data for 2006 and 2011 (the census years). So for 8 of 10 years, full columns of my control variables are blank.
What's the best practice when dealing with this type of missing data problem? I don't think I can use data imputation methods like MI since there's no data say for 2007 to predict 2007 data from (or am I mistaken)?
I'm afraid using mean imputation or just using the closest value (filling in 2007-2010 with 2006 data) will introduce a lot of bias.

This is a mess whatever you do. Suppose foo is a variable available only for census years. Then I would spread the 2006 values to a variable foo2006 for all years and the 2011 values to a variable foo2011 for all years. And similarly for other census-only variables. That might create as many problems as it solves. A simpler alternative is just to decide you can't use the variables that are census only.  Interpolating and extrapolating linearly in the census data might be adequate -- or absurd -- but it's yet another method. Small suburbs can change quite rapidly.

I appreciate the input, Nick! I realize no matter what I do it's going to mess a little bit with the data but I will highly consider your suggestion. I also thought of just using 1 year of census data (e.g. 2011) and treat that as time-invariant, similar to your suggestion.
